# What compatibility do I lose when dropping the -khtml- vendor prefix?

Tags: css, safari, webkit, vendor-prefix

I have bits and pieces of CSS that use the `-webkit-` vendor prefix. For compatibility with "older" versions of Safari, I have the same rule with the `-khtml-` vendor prefix. I am actively uninterested in compatibility with Konqueror and other true KHTML browsers.

For example, I may have the following rules:

```
.menuItem {
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

I understand that modern WebKit browsers internally rewrite all `-khtml-` and `-apple-` rules to be `-webkit-` rules instead. However, that leaves me with the following question:

**In what version of Safari did `-webkit-` become available? That is, what is the version before which Safari would completely ignore my rules?**

I plan to use this information to find out whether my individual rules (such as `-khtml-user-select`) are actually supported by this early version of Safari.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `-webkit-` prefix has been around since [Safari 3](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/WebCore/WebCore-4A93/css/html4.css). The `-khtml-` references in [Safari 2](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/WebCore/WebCore-418.22/khtml/css/html4.css) were replaced from that point on.

**References**

- [Webkit 63854 Changelog](http://trac.webkit.org/export/63854/trunk/WebCore/ChangeLog)
- [Chromium Changelog](https://src.chromium.org/svn/branches/WebKit/472/WebCore/ChangeLog)
- [Webkit Bug 42990](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42990)
- [Unforking of KHTML and WebKit](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2007/07/the-unforking-of-kdes-khtml-and-webkit/)
- [Interview with Lars Knoll, creator of KHTML](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2007/06/ars-at-wwdc-interview-with-lars-knoll-creator-of-khtml/)
- [Companies and Organizations that have contributed to WebKit](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/Companies%20and%20Organizations%20that%20have%20contributed%20to%20WebKit)
- [konqueror/kcmcss.cpp at master · KDE/konqueror](https://github.com/KDE/konqueror/blob/master/settings/konqhtml/css/kcmcss.cpp)

Answer (score 5):

The only browser that uses the `-khtml-` prefix now is a [Konqueror](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konqueror), since it have a very little market share (less than 1%), you can drop it safely.

Answer (score 0):

Basically very less people uses Konqueror, So it is not necessary to use -khtml- prefix

> But if required you, can only use this with the -khtml- prefix